# How can I optimize this query in neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I have a unidirectional graph.
The structure is as follows:
[image]

There are about 20,000 nodes in the graph.
I make the simplest request: `MATCH (b1)-[:NEXT_BAR*10]->(b2) RETURN b1.id, b2.id LIMIT 5`
The request is processed quickly.

But if I increase the number of relationships, the query takes much longer to process. In other words, the speed depends on the number of relationships.
This request takes longer than 5 minutes to complete: `MATCH (b1)-[:NEXT_BAR*10000]->(b2) RETURN b1.id, b2.id LIMIT 5`
This is still a simplified version. The request can have more than two nodes and the number of relationships can still be a range.

How can I optimize a query with a large number of relationships?
Perhaps there are other graph DBMS where there is no such problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to find the last node in the chain? Are you trying to find a specific node in a chain n hops deep? Is it something else?

Comment: I'm trying to find combinations of nodes that meet certain conditions.
Real example: [link](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/m42o/46ckD8KU7)
This code is generated automatically.

Adding conditions to where doesn't help the query speed, which is strange.

The example shows ranges of relationships, but the query takes a long time to process and has a fixed number of relationships.

Answer (score 2):

[Variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) queries have exponential time and memory complexity.

If `R` is the average number of suitable relationships per node, and `D` is the depth of the search, then the complexity is `O(R ** D)`. This complexity will exist in *any* DBMS.

Comment: Yes, but the example specifies a fixed number of relationships, not a variable number

Comment: Why does the speed drop so much when this fixed number of relationships increases?

Comment: As an example, if `R` is 10, then the complexity for a `D` of 10 would be 10**10 (i.e., 10,000,000,000) for a single result. Since you want 5 results, you should multiply that number by 5 (assuming the Cypher planner generates code that will stop as soon as 5 results are found).

Answer (score 1):

The theory is simple here, but there are a couple of intricacies in the query execution.

`-[:NEXT_BAR*10000]-` matches a path that is **precisely 10000** edges in size, so query engine spends some time to find these paths. Another thing to mention is that in `(b1)-[...]- >(b2)`, `b1` and `b2` are not specific, which means that the query engine has to scall all nodes. If there is a limit, yea, scall all should return a limited number of items. The whole execution also depends on the efficiency of variable-length path implementation.

Some of the following might help:

- Is it feasible to start from a specific node?
- If there are branches, the only hope is aggressive filtering because of exponential complexity (as cybersam well explained).
- Use a smaller number in the variable expand, or a range, e.g., `[NEXT_BAR*..10000]`. In this case, the query engine will match any path up to 10000 in size (different semantics, but maybe applicable).
- `*` means the DFS type of execution. On the other hand, [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) might be the right approach. [Memgraph](https://docs.memgraph.com/memgraph) (DISCLAIMER: I'm the co-founder and CTO) also supports [BFS type of execution with filtering lambda](https://docs.memgraph.com/memgraph/reference-overview/graph-algorithms#breadth-first-search).

Here is a Python script I've used to generate and import data into Memgraph. By using small `nodes_no` you can quickly notice the execution patterns.

```py
import mgclient

# Make a connection to the database.
connection = mgclient.connect(
    host='127.0.0.1',
    port=7687,
    sslmode=mgclient.MG_SSLMODE_REQUIRE)
connection.autocommit = True
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Clean and setup database instance.
cursor.execute("""MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n;""")
cursor.execute("""CREATE INDEX ON :Node(id);""")

# Import dataset.
nodes_no = 10
# Create nodes.
for identifier in range(0, nodes_no):
    cursor.execute("""CREATE (:Node {id: "%s"});""" % identifier)
# Create edges.
for identifier in range(1, nodes_no):
    cursor.execute("""
        MATCH (start_node:Node {id: "%s"})
        MATCH (end_node:Node {id: "%s"})
        CREATE (start_node)-[:NEXT_BAR]->(end_node);
    """ % (identifier - 1, identifier))
```